# Window.outerHeight returns 0 when opening new tab. Why?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

I have standard navigation bar that opens new pages and global calculation file where I use `window.outerHeight` to calculate some values. When user wants to open new page in new tab with right click from navigation bar `window.outerHeight` returns `0` and I don't know why?

**Specs:**

- Google Chrome Version 83.0.4103.116
- React 16.13.0

Note: I tested it in Firefox as well and it works normally.

Comment: Could be a timing issue, have you tried to add a timeout and see if it's available just even a second later.

Comment: I switched from outerHeight to innerHeight, as that seems better way for me of doing things then adding timeout.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same issue. I don't know if it is actually a bug in Chrome or a valid value for this corner case of a hidden tab.

I was able to partially get around it by using `window.innerHeight`, which returns the expected value in this hidden tab case. Obviously its value is different from `outerHeight`, but in my use case it was an acceptable workaround.